# B2C Tenant user custom claim

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I've followed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) to add b2c app ID and Object ID to `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml` file. I've then just added the following to my SignUp (SignUpWithMFA) `RelyingParty`

```
<PersistedClaims>
  <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_signupGuid" DefaultValue="SomeRandomValue" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
</PersistedClaims>
```

Then in my SignIn (SignInWithForgetPasswordAndMFA) `RelyingParty`, I've added the following

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_signupGuid" />
```

I would have thought that an additional claim would come through on signin called `signupGuid` with value `SomeRandomValue`, but it doesn't. I'm out of ideas as to what to try next.

**UPDATE**

I had already defined the claim in my custom policy like so

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_signupGuid">
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

In the app, I'm actually just pulling a list of claims currently just to test that the claim is coming through with the correct value, so I understand how to pull the token.

The part that I'm struggling with is adding the custom claim to the user's token. I thought that perhaps just having `extension_signupGuid` as an added output claim in my `RelyingParty` would be sufficient, i.e.

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignInWithForgetPasswordAndMFA" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>...</UserJourneyBehaviors>

  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      ...
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_signupGuid" />   
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

but you're saying I need to make a REST call to retrieve that even though during SignUp, I had persisted that claim as mentioned in my initial post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to make an additional REST call to fetch the claim stored. I needed this `ClaimsProvider` defined as

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ClientId">{Settings:B2CExtensionClientId}</Item>
        <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">{Settings:B2CExtensionApplicationObjectId}</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_signupGuid" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

and in the `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail` `TechnicalProfile`, I needed to configure it as below

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <PersistedClaims>
    ...
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_signupGuid" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:signupGuid}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </PersistedClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

and then just needed to ensure I had an `OutputClaim` for `extension_signupGuid` in my SignIn `RelyingParty` as below

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignInWithForgetPasswordAndMFA" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>...</UserJourneyBehaviors>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      ..
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_signupGuid" />        
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Answer (score 1):

n a B2C tenant, custom claims can be used to store additional user information that is not available in the standard set of claims. Custom claims can be used for a variety of purposes, such as personalization, authorization, and user segmentation.

To add a custom claim to a user in a B2C tenant, you can follow these steps:

Define the custom claim in your B2C tenant: You can define custom claims in your B2C tenant's user flows or in custom policies. To define a custom claim, you'll need to specify its name, data type, and any other relevant attributes.

Add the custom claim to the user's token: Once the custom claim has been defined, you can add it to the user's token by including it as a user attribute in your user flow or custom policy. You can populate the value of the custom claim either from the user input or by using a REST API call to retrieve the value from an external system.

Access the custom claim in your application: Once the custom claim is added to the user's token, you can access it in your application using the standard claims handling mechanisms. For example, you can retrieve the custom claim from the token's payload using a JWT library or by making a call to the Azure AD Graph API.

It's important to note that custom claims can only be added to a user's token during the authentication process. Once the token is issued, the values of the custom claims cannot be modified. If you need to update the value of a custom claim, you'll need to reauthenticate the user to generate a new token with the updated claim value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've added an update to my original post addressing the points you mentioned. I you could take a look...any further advise would be most appreciated.